# Difference between ひま and 空いている

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in nuance between the various words used to describe the concept of "being free"? I have encountered these two:

- 明日ひま
- 明日空いている

but there are probably more alternatives (and I'd like to know about them too).

Answer (score 2):

There are many alternatives, as you imagined. The following is a list of some expressions among many. The list is arranged in the order of politeness, but not so strict.

- 明日、ひま。(very casual, used usually between close friends)
- 明日、あいている。(casual, used usually between friends)
- 明日は、ひまですか。
- 明日は、あいていますか。
- 明日は、時間がありますか。
- 明日は、おひまですか。(polite)
- 明日は、あいてみえますか。(polite)
- 明日、時間はおありですか。(polite)
- 明日は、おひまな時間がおありですか。(very polite)

Comment: So the only difference is the level of politeness right?